# Labels Not Showing Up On Map

Tags: qgis

I've just tried following a simple tutorial to get familiar with QGIS. I'm trying to get a label to show up on a map without success. I followed the tutorial twice with the same result. In the Layer Styling window I've tried changing settings but do not see the label on the map. What am I not seeing?

[image: Oslo Harbour With New Islands But No Labels]

Comment: Try `'island'` instead for your labels. `"island"` refers to a column named `island` which is probably non-existent, while single quotation marks represent a string value.

Comment: Also, rather set your labels to `points` or `mm` for size instead of `map units`, otherwise you will get 10 m high labels, which are hardly visible at your current scale.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Both comments helped me.